# calculation of points for each student

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I want to calculate the remaining points.

in calculation formula : total points =TotalPoints - plenty + Bonus
total points 100
eg. 1

| st_id | plenty | Bonus | remaining Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 0 | 95 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 93 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 91 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 90 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 99 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 96 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 94 |

first row calculation for st_id 1: 100 -5 +0= 95

second row calculation for st_id1: 95 - 3 +1=93     here i have to take the previous remaining points. and so on...

can i make a function or use cte to calculate remaining point.
or any other solution for this problem.

Comment: I didn't understand the meaning of  "total points =TotalPoints - plenty + Bonus" because where do I get the "TotalPoint". There is no such column in your question table. Another thing is that, your left hand side is also " total points". What are the differences between these 2 total points. Can you explain little more?

Comment: What makes row1 first and row2 second, which column determines the order of rows?

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets (technically "multisets").  There is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering.

Your results depend on an ordering, so let me assume that you have such a column.

The solution is then cumulative sums:

```
select t.*,
       100 - sum(plenty - bonus) over (partition by st_id order by <ordering col>) as remaining
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am bit confused, how did you get 100 for the first row in formula "first row calculation for st_id 1: 100 -5 +0= 95" and 95 for second formula "st_id1: 95 - 3 +1=93". Finally, I anticipated that, you might have a column named TotalPoint in your table, so, I write a code. Please Check and let me know->

```
DECLARE @Points table(st_id int,plenty int,Bonus int,TotalPoints  int);

INSERT INTO @Points (st_id, plenty,Bonus,TotalPoints) VALUES (1, 5,0,100);
INSERT INTO @Points (st_id, plenty,Bonus,TotalPoints) VALUES (1, 3,1,95);
INSERT INTO @Points (st_id, plenty,Bonus,TotalPoints) VALUES (1, 2,0,91);
INSERT INTO @Points (st_id, plenty,Bonus,TotalPoints) VALUES (1, 3,0,90);
INSERT INTO @Points (st_id, plenty,Bonus,TotalPoints) VALUES (2, 1,0,99);
INSERT INTO @Points (st_id, plenty,Bonus,TotalPoints) VALUES (2, 3,1,96);
INSERT INTO @Points (st_id, plenty,Bonus,TotalPoints) VALUES (2, 2,0,94);

Select *,(TotalPoints-plenty-Bonus) AS RemainingPoint FROM @Points
```